# AHK, how to use + in the script

Tags: autohotkey

In AutoHotKey there are few keys that mean something else like + means shift
I want to write script which will be similar like this but to pressing "+"

```
$*b::
  While GetKeyState("b","P")
  {
    Send, {Blind}b
    Sleep, 10 ; every 10 miliseconds
  }
Return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hotkey with any button by following the steps in the docs [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys). StackOverflow doesn't like links, so here's what's behind it:

1. Ensure that at least one script is running that is using the keyboard hook. You can tell if a script has the keyboard hook by opening its main window and selecting "View->Key history" from the menu bar.
2. Double-click that script's tray icon to open its main window.
3. Press one of the "mystery keys" on your keyboard.
4. Select the menu item "View->Key history"
5. Scroll down to the bottom of the page. Somewhere near the bottom are the key-down and key-up events for your key. NOTE: Some keys do not generate events and thus will not be visible here. If this is the case, you cannot directly make that particular key a hotkey because your keyboard driver or hardware handles it at a level too low for AutoHotkey to access. For possible solutions, see further below.
6. If your key is detectable, make a note of the 3-digit hexadecimal value in the second column of the list (e.g. 159).
7. To define this key as a hotkey, follow this example:

```
SC159:: ; Replace 159 with your key's value.
MsgBox, %A_ThisHotkey% was pressed.
return
```

Comment: On my keyboard leyout there is no 1 over my Q key there is + key so i want to press the "+" wich is up the Q in eng layout there is 1 i literally pres + only + nothing more but work with modifyers

Comment: Oh. Maybe `plus::`?

Comment: It doesnt work like this it says it dont know what "plus" is

Comment: Just edited my answer, these steps should work

Comment: Glad I could help! Please click the checkmark to mark my answer as accepted, so other people can find it in the future :)